# How to prevent BabelJS from making global variable of 'arguments' keyword?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

In a project I have this BabelJS configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2016"]
}
```

And somewhere in the code there is a method using the standard JS 'arguments' keyword to deal with a dynamic range of parameters. Something like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  // pass all arguments with spread operator
  someOtherFunction(...arguments); 
}

myFunction('one', 'two', 3, {number: 4});
```

So far so good but when BabelJS is done, it has (1) defined 'arguments' as a global variable and (2) also in a way that is bound to fail in itself:

```
var arguments = arguments;
```

Is there a way to stop BabelJS from doing this? Either by configuration or some special comment to make exceptions?

Comment: Don't use an arrow function when you want to use the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the magic `arguments` variable.

```
(...args) => {
  // pass all arguments
  someOtherFunction(...args);
}
```

If you, for some reason, must use the `arguments` variable (hint, you *almost always* don't), you have to use `.apply()` like you would before ES5 was a thing.

```
(function() {
  someOtherFunction.apply(null, arguments);
})
```

Comment: Great! Thank you @Madara!

Comment: Yes I didn't want to use 'apply' although that is a possibility.
I'm happy with your answer to avoid the issue but I still wonder why BabelJS doesn't consider 'arguments' as the keyword that it is and creates a global variable.

Comment: @Jos Arrow functions don't have arguments `var test = ()=>console.log(arguments);test()` so babel probably assumes that `arguments` is a global variable